# magento 1.7.0.0 security patch SUPEE-10415 installation issue - Hunk #1 FAILED

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, security, installation, supee-10415

[image]

Please help me to get rid of this problem and help me to install this SUPEE-10415 security patch on Magento 1.7.0.0.

Comment: Have you got all previous patches installed? Refer to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=192164130 as to which patches you need for version 1.7.0.0.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes i had solved this issue after installing some of the previous patches